# What exactly does "Highly Scalable" property of Google datastore means?

Tags: database, google-app-engine, database-design, google-cloud-datastore, nosql

Simple doubt ,does it means it can handle billion+ entities(rows in mysql sense)in a kind(table in mysql sense) without any sharding as well as without compromising any performance ?

Comment: Scalability has a few dimensions: vertical scalability refers to the potential of upgrading a single host, horizontal scalability refers to the potential of clustering (multiple hosts). Then there are some other scalability dimensions depending on the grade of abstraction you're using. I'm pretty sure Google has no specification for that term - it's just a marketing line.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak.kk.so in my case I have a billion+ entities and expecting to grow another billion with 15 properties for each entities.there are  no relational operations.is datastore right choice ?

Comment: No idea. If it doesn't cost you anything, I suggest just trying.

Comment: I have seen half-a-billion tables running on MSSQL/Oracle/PostgreSQL on a single machine, so I guess you can take it much further if you need to.

Comment: Highly scalable: >1M queries/second per project, >100B entities, >1PB data. Running across multiple zones & regions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can handle billions of entities with no sharding.

The performance of the datastore queries is not dependent on the number of entities that you have. It depends on the number of entities that you want to retrieve. In other words, you will get 100 entities in the same time whether you only have 100 entities or 1 billion entities.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can handle billions of entities in a kind without compromising performance. However, "without sharding" is questionable. By default, all your entities are available for Google to "shard" however they see fit to meet the demands of your app. When I say "shard" here, I mean spread your entities across machines or datacenters as they see fit. Sharding is not something you ever need to manage yourself.

You can, however, restrict sharding (in this sense) by putting multiple entities in the same entity group (i.e. by giving multiple entities the same `parent`). This is something you should avoid when possible, so that you do not restrict how Google can optimize your data with sharding. However, if you need to access many entities within a single transaction, you may need to make entity groups. More information on why and when you'd want to is available [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/structuring_for_strong_consistency).

By the way, Google may also make multiple copies of your data in multiple locations around the world to increase read throughput, if that's what their algorithms determine is most optimal.